# English version of mindmap on Xi Jinping Thought

Tags: china, summary-request, xi-jinping, xi-jinping-thought

According to an [article](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/politics/article/2169151/simple-guide-xi-jinping-thought-heres-how-chinas-official-media) in Hong Kong's *South China Morning Post*, China's *People’s Daily* published a quite complicated mindmap to summarize and explain [Xi Jinping's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_Jinping) Thought. What are the key points of this doctrine according to this mindmap (e.g. bullet points 1 to 30) and does an English version exist as well?

A version with higher resolution can be viewed by clicking on the image.
[image: President Xi's mind map]

Comment: Do you mean "does a translation of this particular mindmap exist?" The answer is probably "no" so this isn't a good fit for this site. Resource requests are off topic.

Comment: @JamesK - [this meta question and the most voted answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/are-requests-for-references-on-topic) suggests to allow such questions as long as they are narrow enough. As you do not expect to find any translation, I think this question satisfy the "narrow enough" criteria.

Comment: @Drux - can you find a larger image? (bigger even than [this one](http://n.sinaimg.cn/front/159/w1600h2559/20181018/sa8t-hmivixn1791731.jpg) ) I have tried some online OCR tool, but I think the text is too small to be properly recognized.

Comment: @Alexei Currently I only have this one sample, but I will try. And thx for your helpful link into meta.

Comment: @Alexei The one you identified is also the largest one I have found so far.

Comment: There is a PDF version at https://cdn.static-economist.com/sites/default/files/pdfs/TE_ximindmap.pdf

Comment: @PaulJohnson Excellent, the surrounding [article](https://www.economist.com/china/2018/11/08/china-is-struggling-to-explain-xi-jinping-thought) is well worth reading as well.

Comment: Damn. That is one of the most impressive illustrations I've ever seen of something like a person's political philosophy.